# user authorization in custom component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7, joomla2.5

hi I am developing custom component in joomla 1.7 I want to restrict user task based on user groups. I have created table and saved all the controller names and tasks and saved the  permissions for the previous tasks with user group id. In central com_component.php file I check the user permissions and authorized the taks with controller. This is working really well. What I want to know is can I use addACL() or authorized() functions to do this which is I really don't understand correctly. Bcoz Here I want use both controller and task together.

Comment: It would be very helpful to show some code.  Especially the outline of what you are doing, then what you are thinking of adding.

Answer (score 2):

Developing a component with the Access Control List is described on Joomla! documentations in detail ([link](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_14)). I think the first thing to do is follow the instructions described there. There is even sample code that you can download and use.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin 'GroupJive' for the Community Builder component has ways to do what you are looking for. I would look to that project at least for a guideline. I will be digging into a similar challenge this weekend and if I find code without the need for the component I will let you know.